# Get all lines that enclose a point

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-statistics

I use QGIS and I have a point and the road network. I need to automatically extract the road names that enclose the specific point. [image]
Nearest neighbor analysis and buffer zones cannot do the job, because in many cases the point is closer, as a matter of measured distance, to neighbor roads and not the enclosing ones.
Are there any ideas on how only the enclosing roads could be extracted?

Comment: Maybe, convert the enclosing area (consisting of a series of lines) to a polygon, with attributes of what roads make up the polygon walls--then you can do a simple select by overlapping location. In this example, point "145699" falls within polygon "roada_roadb_roadc_roadd."

Answer (score 3):

About my test data:

1. Like OSM Road Data every single road geometry ends at a crossroad.
2. Every road has an unique ID.

**SOLUTION I**

If there are the two assumptions:

1. Roads are building quarters.
2. You are working in a metric system.

The idea is to increase/decrease the X and Y coordinates of the point. If you work within a metric system you can go 1m to the East of your point, create a new point and create a line with the original point. You're going further to the East until the line is intersecting a road. To look for an intersection in the West you have subtract 1m from the original X coordinate. The same for the Y coordinate. If there is no road in the North/East/South/West the counter stops at 1000(m). When you know there could be a road within a distance of more then 1000m you have to change this value.

You could solve the task with the following code:

**Edited**

```
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "point":
        startpoint = lyr

for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "roads":
        roads = lyr

startpoint_iter = startpoint.getFeatures()
for feature in startpoint_iter:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    if geom.type() == QGis.Point:
        xy = geom.asPoint()
        x,y = xy[0], xy[1]

line_start = QgsPoint(x,y)      

def reached(direction, count_m):
    road_reached = None
    road = None
    count=1
    while road_reached < 1 and count <=count_m:
        count += 1
        if direction == 'N':
            line_end = QgsPoint(x, y+count)
        if direction == 'E':
            line_end = QgsPoint(x+count,y)
        if direction == 'S':
            line_end = QgsPoint(x,y-count)
        if direction == 'W':
            line_end = QgsPoint(x-count,y)
        line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start,line_end])
        for f in roads.getFeatures():
            if line.intersects(f.geometry()):
                road_reached = 1
                road = f['name']
                print road

reached('N', 1000)
reached('E', 1000)
reached('S', 1000)
reached('W', 1000)
```

Another example to show that road e in the East is not recognized as a nearby road of the point.

[image]

How to call the function and output:

```
>>>>reached('N', 1000)
road a
>>>>reached('E', 1000)
road b
>>>>reached('S', 1000)
road c
>>>>reached('W', 1000)
road d
```

If there are more than 4 roads enclosing the point you have to look in more directions (change both X and Y). Or you could change the azimuth of your line, means you could rotate it by one degree within the range 0-360°.

**SOLUTION II**

Inspired from the comment you can also `Polygonize` your roads first. Therefor you can use a tool from QGIS: `Processing > Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Polygonize`. Rename the temporary layer to `polygon`. Assuming that you only want to have the road names for the point which is completely enclosed by roads. Otherwise you have to use **SOLUTION I**. This only works if all roads are connected (snapped)!

[image]

First the point has to intersects with the polygon. The idea is now that both, start `AND` end point of an enclosing line have to intersect with the polygon.

```
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "point":
        startpoint = lyr

for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "polygon":
        poly = lyr

for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "roads":
        roads = lyr

for h in startpoint.getFeatures():
    for g in poly.getFeatures():
        if h.geometry().intersects(g.geometry()):
            poly_geom = g.geometry()
            for f in roads.getFeatures():
                geom = f.geometry().asPolyline()
                start_point = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(geom[0]))
                end_point = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(geom[-1]))
                if poly_geom.intersects(start_point) and poly_geom.intersects(end_point):
                    print f['name']
```

The output:

```
road c
road b
road e
road f
```